# JavaScript replace text between two special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I whould like to replace everything between the `;#` characters with a new line (`<br>`). How can i do this in JavaScript?

**Example:**

String:

> Beilagenteller - Mixed vegetables plate;#369;#Fischfilet mit Kräutersoße - Fish fillet, herbs sauce,;#183;#Rinderroulade "Hausfrauen Art", (S) Soße - Beef olive with sauce

Result:

> Beilagenteller - Mixed vegetables plate
> Fischfilet mit Kräutersoße - Fish fillet, herbs sauce,
> Rinderroulade "Hausfrauen Art", (S) Soße - Beef olive with sauce

Comment: Mhhmmm... Fischfilet mit Kräutersoße - such a delicious question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the value between the `;#`s is always numeric, you can use the regular expression `/;#\d*;#/g` within a `replace()` call on the string:

```js
var input = 'Beilagenteller - Mixed vegetables plate;#369;#Fischfilet mit Kräutersoße - Fish fillet, herbs sauce,;#183;#Rinderroulade "Hausfrauen Art", (S) Soße - Beef olive with sauce';

var output = input.replace(/;#\d*;#/g, "<br>");

document.write(output);
```

To show what the regular expression does, here is [a visualisation](http://regexper.com/#%2F%3B%23%5Cd*%3B%23%2Fg):

[image: Example]

Comment: @NagyIstvan: Just FYI: It is an SO etiquette to accept the working answers that were provided first.

Comment: yep.. that's why I accepted Neil Villareal's answer, he beat you by 1 minute :)

Comment: ooo, nope, sorry, your answer was the first one

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try this:

```
var str = "Beilagenteller - Mixed vegetables plate;#369;#Fischfilet mit Kräutersoße - Fish fillet, herbs sauce,;#183;#Rinderroulade \"Hausfrauen Art\", (S) Soße - Beef olive with sauce";

str = str.replace(/;#[0-9]*;#/g, "<br/>");

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the folowing code

```
address="Beilagenteller - Mixed vegetables plate;#369;#Fischfilet mit Kräutersoße - Fish fillet, herbs sauce,;#183;#Rinderroulade 'Hausfrauen Art', (S) Soße - Beef olive with sauce"



address= str.replace(/;#[0-9]*;#/g, "\n");
```

Comment: Risky, especially if you go with non-greedy. If you have a string like: "some text#123;#here and#234;# some text there" it might actually find a single match between the first and the fourth "#"

Comment: To make it non-greedy, add a question mark after "*": /#.*?#/
(edit: for some reason, the star is not visible... there's a star between . and ?)